# What is .NET MVC architecture?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

What is .NET MVC architecture?

Comment: There is a lot of websites are explaining mvc here
http://www.asp.net/mvc/
 you should check it , this is not a specific question

Comment: This is a classic example of why it is dumb to say that SO should have an answer to every technical question. There's no point in a crowd-sourced effort to key in by hand every combination of useful search terms and redirect them to results you can already find in Google with those exact same search terms.

Comment: there is no such thing as ".net mvc architecture".

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

> Model–View–Controller (MVC) is an
>   architectural pattern used in software
>   engineering. The pattern isolates
>   "domain logic" (the application logic
>   for the user) from input and
>   presentation (GUI), permitting
>   independent development, testing and
>   maintenance of each.